# What is the equivalent to Page.ResolveUrl in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the equivalent to Page.ResolveUrl in ASP.NET MVC available in the Controller?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It is [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx):

ASPX:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/style.css") %>" type="text/css" />
```

Razor:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: And don't overlook that "~/" bit like I did, as it's important

Answer (score 43):

This should do what you're looking for...

```
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")
```

Comment: Although I mostly use Url.Content, this method can be useful as it is static and doesn't require a request context, like Url.Content.

Comment: This can be used on a .ascx that is consumed by both web forms and MVC.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a whole bunch of ways to resolve a path that uses that [application root operator (`~`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178116(v=vs.100))

- [`UrlHelper.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content)
- [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath)
- [`WebPageExecutingBase.Href`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.webpageexecutingbase.href)
- [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.virtualpathutility.toabsolute)
- [`Control.ResolveUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl)

To call any method with inline code on an asp.net page, the method either needs to be exposed as an instance variable on the current object, or available as a static/shared method.

A typical MVC page gives us access to quite a few of these as properties via the [`WebViewPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/gg402005(v=vs.118)). Ever wonder when you type `@ViewData`, you get magically wired up to the ViewData?  That's because you have hit a property exposed by the MVC page you're on.

So to call these methods, we don't necessarily refer to the type they represent, but the instance property that exposes them.

We can call the above instance methods like this (respectively):

```
href="@Url.Content("~/index.html")" 
href="@Server.MapPath("~/index.html")" 
href="@Href("~/index.html")"
```

We can do this to call a shared method that doesn't need an instance:

```
href="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/index.html")"
```

AFAIK, an MVC page doesn't automatically create an instance of anything from the System.Web.UI namespace, from which `ResolveUrl` inherits.  If, for some reason, you really wanted to use that particular method, you could just new up a control and use the methods it exposes, but I would **highly recommend against it**.

```vb
@Code
    Dim newControl As New System.Web.UI.Control
    Dim resolvedUrl = newControl.ResolveUrl("~/index.html")
End Code
href="@resolvedUrl"
```

#### That all said, I would recommend using `@Url.Content` as it fits best with MVC paradigms

Answer (score 3):

`UrlHelper.Content()` does the same thing as `Control.ResolveUrl().`

For Further References:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/02/18/asp-net-mvc-tip-47-ndash-using-resolveurl-in-an-html.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this anymore in Razor v2.0/ASP.NET MVC 4.

Just use the "~" in a razor page and it will resolve it for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

[Source](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I find @Href not being enough in the way it deals with query strings in a URL. I prefer to wrap it inside the Raw method:

```
<script>
var isKendoWindow = false;
var myTimeOut;
clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
var sessionTimeout = (@Session.Timeout * 60000) - 5;
function doRedirect() {
    if (!isKendoWindow)
        window.location.href = '@Html.Raw(Href("~/Logon.aspx?brandid=" + SessionController.LandingBrandId + "&errCode=5055"))';
}
myTimeOut = setTimeout('doRedirect()', sessionTimeout);
</script>
```

Or you can create your own version like this:

```
 public static IHtmlString ResolveUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url)
 {    
     var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
     return htmlHelper.Raw(urlHelper.Content(url));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issue:

Resolve the url in a code block at the top of the page or in code behind.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_IndexLayout.cshtml";
    String img1 = Url.Content("~/img/people11.jpg");
}
```

Then use the variable in the html.

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-8" style="background-image: url('@img1');"> </div>
```

Comment: P.S. This method also works around the problem of the page not parsing correctly with multiple nested quotes. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35c09604-84eb-4539-8361-883376cfba85/problem-with-nested-single-and-double-quotes-in-embedded-code-blocks-in-the-markup?forum=aspwebforms

Answer (score -5):

```
Server.MapPath() //returna full path
```

or

```
url.content()
```

Comment: Doesnt Server.MapPath() return the physical disk path rather than expanding a full URL, like Page.ResolveUrl("~") ?

Comment: yeah your right it does, you could hack around it but `url.content` is available instead!

Answer (score -7):

try using Server.MapPath().