# Can I use relative path in Open Graph?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to set a relative path to `og:image` metadata like this:

```html
<meta name="og:image" content="/images/view.png">
```

On Sharing Debugger I have the following warning:

> Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

There is any way to use a relative path in Open Graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, og:image won't work with a  relative path.

More info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858694/7068514

Comment: When an answer already exists, please close the question as a duplicate. Don't duplicate the answer (or link to it).