# og:image content not working for local image url

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add image url to the meta og:image tag in my ReactJS project, but when I use Facebook Debugger to test it keeps saying invalid image url. Can anyone show me how to fix this?
[image: This is my folder directory.]
And my code in public/index.html is

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1500"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="786"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="src/asset/img/IMG_0579.png"/>
```

Comment: Apparently it can't be done according to this:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146042/can-i-use-relative-path-in-open-graph)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open graph can resolve relative url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858577/open-graph-can-resolve-relative-url)